# Setting Up Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, rvm

I'm pretty much new to developing rails applications. I'm trying to setup everything on Ubuntu 11.04. I have installed RVM ( 1.8.7 & 1.9.2 ) and have installed rubygems. But when I try to install rails using

> sudo gem install rails

I get this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find rails (>= 0) amongst [] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1182:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What do you get for `ruby -v`? I don't think you're loading rvm's ruby.

Comment: I get this: ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [i686-linux]. Do you mean rvm use <version>?

Comment: can you also post the exact command you're typing in to get this error?

Comment: I used sudo gem install rails, and got the error above

Comment: what's the output of '$ which gem'?

Comment: Did you install rvm as non-root user? Then don't use `sudo`

Comment: the output of which gem: /home/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/gem

Comment: I'm not sure of what non-root user means, but I installed it using bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)

Comment: What do you get from `rvm current`? You shouldn't use `sudo` with RVM.

Comment: I get this w/ rvm current: ruby-1.9.2-p180, when I use gem install rails, I get 2 error, no such file to load --zlib etc...

Comment: It looks like you don't have zlib packages installed - http://beginrescueend.com/packages/zlib/ will fix it up for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have installed RVM you should not use sudo for installing gem. Also, from you previous comment, you maybe have installed RVM in the HOME directory of root user which is not what you want.
You should be able to follow [this guide](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/) wrote by Ryan Bigg, it contain very good explanation step by step about how to setup RVM and Rails on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed RubyGems separately from installing a ruby in RVM then that's probably your problem.  When you install a ruby it installs a RubyGems along with that ruby for you to use while using that ruby.  Also make sure your .bashrc and .bash_profile are setup correctly based on the RVM installation instructions.  Did you do a sigle-user or a system-wide install?

Comment: I installed RubyGems using these commands: $ sudo ruby setup.rb &
$ sudo gem update --system. I've also added if [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]]  ; then source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ; fi at the end of my .bashrc file. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with single user and system wide installs. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: The only way to install RVM is through either of those two options.  If you ran "bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)" as root then it would be a system-wide install, but otherwise it would be a single user install.  In either case, as soon as you install a ruby you have the gem command available (without having to use sudo).  You may have to run "rvm package install zlib" first, and then reinstall your rubies, and then run "gem install rails" in whichever ruby you have selected.  Go over the tutorial that Adrien gave you and you should have no problems :)

Comment: This site probably explains the install process best. http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/